# Configuração do NotificationCompat

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment

Tenho um app simples para enviar Notificações, vibrar e tocar ao receber. No meu android 4.3 ele funciona, no outro meu celular com android 9 ele só da o toque, não mostra a notificação e nem vibra.

Método de notificação está em apenas um botão:

```
public void gerarNotificacao(View view) {
        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent p = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, atividade2.class), 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        builder.setTicker("Ticket Texto");
        builder.setContentTitle("Título");
        //builder.setContentText("Descrição");
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);
        builder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher_background));
        builder.setContentIntent(p);

        NotificationCompat.InboxStyle style = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();
        String[] descs = new String[]{"Descrição 1", "Descrição 2", "Descrição 3", "Descrição 4"};
        for (int i = 0; i < descs.length; i++) {
            style.addLine(descs[i]);
        }
        builder.setStyle(style);

        // Vibração
        Notification n = builder.build();
        n.vibrate = new long[]{150, 300, 150, 600};
        n.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        nm.notify(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, n);

        // Toque
        try {
            Uri som = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            Ringtone toque = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this, som);
            toque.play();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
```

No `androidManifest` coloquei essa permissão:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

Creio que seja uma solução simples, obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

como diz a documentação do android.

> A partir do Android 8.0 (nível de API 26), todas as notificações devem ser atribuídas a um canal. Para cada canal, você pode definir o comportamento visual e auditivo aplicado a todas as notificações nesse canal. Em seguida, os usuários podem alterar essas configurações e decidir quais canais de notificação do seu aplicativo devem ser intrusivos ou visíveis.

Você nesse caso precisara implementar os canais na sua classe que recebe e cria as notificações. 
[Como criar canais para as novas versões do android](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels)